# ReplayKit stops buffering after going to background repeatedly

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I'm trying to use ReplayKit to create a live broadcast inside of my app.
Basically I want to share my screen and see the screen of the other user.

To get the buffers, ReplayKit offers the next function:

```
func startCapture(handler captureHandler: ((CMSampleBuffer, RPSampleBufferType, Error?) -> Void)?, completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```

So this is my method to startup ReplayKit and get the buffers:

```
private func startRecording() {
    RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture(handler: { (sampleBuffer, bufferType, error) in
        switch bufferType {

        case RPSampleBufferType.video:
            // Handle buffer and send it to server
            break

        case RPSampleBufferType.audioApp:
            break
        case RPSampleBufferType.audioMic:
            break
        }

    }, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

This works perfectly, but I'm facing the next issue; if the screen gets changes constantly, like a flashing button, when I send the app to background and come back several times ReplayKit stops calling its capture handler.

Maybe the problem is that the function `startCapture` is made to record the screen for a limited time, and not for a live broadcast.

[I have made an example in Github](https://github.com/DiegoQuimbo/TestingReplayKit) with a flashing button that shows the problem that I'm having; ReplayKit runs normally until going to background repeatedly; then it stops, and the only way to make it work again is to reboot the device.